# How to map a calss that inherits an asbtract class and implements an interface at the same time in nHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

Imagine we have this entities:

```
public interface ISomeone
{
}

public abstract class Parent
{
}

public class Child : Parent , ISomeone
{
}

public class Orphan : ISomeone
{
}

public class MyHeart
{
  public ISomeone Person {get;set;}
}
```

then how is possible to mapping theses all classes in nhibernate?
I prefer to use separate tables for "Parent", "Orphane" and "MyHeart" class.
"Parent" , "Orphan" and "MyHeart" should be persist as aggrigate root and MyHeart could has a relation to any entity that implemented "ISomeone" interface. so it could expande across diffrent entity types with diffrent id form diffrent tables

Comment: I think you should first ask yourself how you want you data to look. This is unrelated to the type of ORM framework you're using. The example you have given here seems very hypothetical and not a representation of what you are actually looking for. None of the classes really have any properties. Why is `Parent` not implementing `ISomeone`? And why do you want an interface or abstract class to represent your datamodel which is something very concrete and not abstract at all?

Comment: Note that I'm not saying you can't use abstract classes to map your data but I'm not convinced if that's what you need/should do.

Comment: I would agree with Xerillio, this is possible, however, how do you expect to use 'Parent'?. MyHeart has a reference to an ISomeone, however, the only implementations of that interface is 'Child' & 'Orphan'. Is that what youre expecting, that MyHeart.Person will either be a 'Child' or 'Orphan'? If so, it seems like the abstract class wont affect your mapping. If not, I dont see how the abstract class plays into your mapping here.

Comment: thanks guys to replaying. I want use "Parent", "Orphane" and "MyHeart" as aggrigate root and all of then should be persist. Parent and its inheritors should be persist in the same table mayne discriminator could play some role here.but the point is MyHeart that refers to some entity that implement ISomeone. when MyHeart retrive from db should be refer to correct entity. I hope it could make clear

Comment: I did some edit to more explanation what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution
the "Any" method is the answer, briefly with this method we define some meta value for each possible value for IPerson in another world every class that implements this interface should be define in "Any" method then nHibernate persists the Id and the MetaValue.

The mapping by code for my example would be like this:

```
public class MyHeartMapping : ClassMapping<MyHeart>
{
    public MyHeartMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, x => x.Generator(Generators.Native));

        Any(p => p.Person, typeof(long), m => {

            m.MetaValue("Child", typeof(Child));
            m.MetaValue("Orphane", typeof(Orphane));
            m.Columns(i => i.Name("PersonId"), c => c.Name("ClassName")); });
    }
}

public class ParentMapping : ClassMapping<Parent>
{
    public ParentMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, x => x.Generator(Generators.Native));
        Discriminator(c => c.Column("Discriminator"));
    }
}

public class ChildMapping : SubclassMapping<Child>
{
    public ChildMapping()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Child");
    }
}

public class OrphaneMapping : ClassMapping<Orphane>
{
    public OrphaneMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, x => x.Generator(Generators.Native));
    }
}
```